# If $f(x) = x - [x]$ then find the derivative at $x = 0.5$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $f(x) = x - [x]$ where $[\,\,\,]$ denotes the greatest integer function, then find $f'\left(\dfrac12\right)$.

My approach:
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\Big((x+h) - [x+h]\Big) - \Big((x) - [x]\Big)}{h}$$
$$\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{x = 1/2} = \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\Big((1/2+h) - [1/2+h]\Big) - \Big(1/2 - [1/2]\Big)}{h}$$
$$\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{x = 1/2} = \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(1/2+h) - [1/2+h] -(1/2 - 0)}{h}$$
$$\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{x = 1/2} = \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{h - [1/2+h]}{h}$$
Since $h$ is tending to $0%$, the greatest integer function $[1/2+h]$ will be $0$ and hence the derivative will be $1$.

---

Is this approach correct?

Also, I'm wondering if there is another interesting method to solve the problem as I'm seeing the derivative question involving the greatest integer function first time in my book.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in (0,1)$, so $f'(1/2)=x'=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all that. If $x\in(0,1)$, then $f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor=x$, and therefore $f'\left(\frac12\right)=1$.

Comment: Yeah, subtracting the integer part just leaves you with the beginning of the $y=x$ function but repeated in a cycle of length 1. So the derivative is exactly the same as $y=x$ except where x is a whole number multiple of the cycle length 1 (so just a whole number) because there the function jumps back down again. At those points the derivative isn't defined.